# gujarati font type in android application

Tags: android

i want to display gujarati font in android application

Comment: I allow you to do it!

Comment: You will have to provide more details.  What type of application?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I also permit such a thing!  One more vote and you should be ok.

Answer (score 5):

put the gujarati font file in your assets folder of your project, then, in your code, you can use setTYpeface() function to set the font for the text view.

first:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/xyz.otf");
```

then:

```
text.setTypeFace(tf);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks rahul my problem is sloved

Comment: hi himansu  can you expalin me how to possible

Comment: no himanshu , this is not working. I tried it with so many gujarati fonts.